# Seeking resources for building a plugin in ROS 2 and availability of Gazebo battery plugin

Tags: gazebo, ros2, ros-humble

I'm currently working on a project that requires building a plugin in ROS 2, specifically for integration with Gazebo. I've checked the Gazebo website for tutorials, but I couldn't find any specific ones dedicated to ROS 2 plugin development.

I would appreciate it if you could provide me with any recommended resources, tutorials, or examples for learning how to build a plugin in ROS 2, particularly for Gazebo integration.

Additionally, I'm wondering if there is an existing Gazebo battery plugin available for ROS 2. I'm looking to simulate a battery model in Gazebo for my ROS 2 application.

I have found for battery plugin for ROS: [here](https://github.com/nilseuropa/gazebo_ros_battery) and [here](https://github.com/pooyanjamshidi/brass_gazebo_battery)

Thank you in advance for any guidance or information you can provide!

Comment: Can you be more specific about which versions you are trying to integrate here?  Gazebo classic and modern Gazebo (Fortress, Garden, etc), have slightly different ways of creating plugins and interacting with ROS.

Comment: i'm using gazebo classic (version 11.10.2
) and ros2 version: Humble